# With Python... Go to the site, check for a new zip file and

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, zip

I need to go to the site, check for a new zip file and download this new zip file. Then unzip the file.
I'm not doing well, despite getting close.

I tried to find the file on the site, but the closest one was with the code below.

```
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('http://www.caixa.gov.br/site/paginas/downloads.aspx')

about = r.html.find('#ctl00_ctl59_g_25db0873_16a3_46ff_b78a_a48f0566ce2f_rptCategoriasDownloads_ctl437_lkbCategoria', first=True)

sel = 'div > ul > li> a'

print(r.html.find(sel, first=True).text)

print (about.html)
```

I hope the script will download the newest file:
http://www.caixa.gov.br/site/paginas/downloads.aspx

> Orçamento Geral da União – Base de Dados
>   DB_GESTORES_12_09_2019 (So far this is the newest file.)

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is to me. You are using the correct id for identifying the link. Is the problem with then mimicking the PostBac in order to get the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Importando bibliotecas usadas 
import schedule 
import time 
import os
import requests, re
from datetime import datetime
from zipfile import ZipFile

# Capturar data do dia e formatar
# dia de hoje
dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
# dia de ontem
last_day = int(dateTimeObj.strftime("%d")) - 1
last_day = (str(last_day) +  dateTimeObj.strftime("_%m_%Y"))

# Variáveis de configurações 
dir_local = 'C:/Users/login/Documents/Projetos/Modelagem - Dados - Caixa/banco_bi_caixa_ogu/'
db_gest = 'DB_GESTORES_'

last_day = db_gest + last_day + '.zip'
filename = db_gest + timestampStr + '.zip'
#filename = 'DB_GESTORES_19_09_2019.zip' # descomentar para teste

url_ontem = 'http://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/Orcamento-Geral-da-Uniao-Base-de-Dados/' + last_day
url = 'http://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/Orcamento-Geral-da-Uniao-Base-de-Dados/' + filename

# Função baixar (arquivo de ontem)
def baixar_ontem():

    # Usando requests, site com redirecionamento e cookies  
    myfile_ontem = requests.get(url_ontem, allow_redirects=True, cookies={'fhauth':'cacb87b4f894bc0525ccd3004d3a6dab580acd07'}).content

    # Verificar existência do arquivo filename pelo conteúdo dentro do myfile 

    if re.search("File Not Found", str(myfile_ontem)):
        print("Não foi possível efetuar o download ou arquivo não existe! Arquivo: " + last_day)
    else:
        with open(dir_local + last_day, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(myfile_ontem)

# Função baixar
def baixar():

    # Usando requests, site com redirecionamento e cookies  
    myfile = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, cookies={'fhauth':'cacb87b4f894bc0525ccd3004d3a6dab580acd07'}).content

    # Verificar existência do arquivo filename pelo conteúdo dentro do myfile 

    if re.search("File Not Found", str(myfile)):
        print("Não foi possível efetuar o download ou arquivo não existe! Arquivo: " + filename)
    else:
        with open(dir_local + filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(myfile)

# Função extrair
def extrair():
    if os.path.exists(dir_local + filename):
        unzip = ZipFile(dir_local + filename)
        unzip.extractall(dir_local)
        unzip.close()
    elif os.path.exists(dir_local + last_day):
        unzip = ZipFile(dir_local + last_day)
        unzip.extractall(dir_local)
        unzip.close()
    else:
        print('Função Extrair: Arquivo não existe')

# Remover o arquivo "filename" ZIP
def remover():
    if os.path.exists(dir_local + filename):
        os.remove(dir_local + filename)
    elif os.path.exists(dir_local + last_day):
        os.remove(dir_local + last_day)
    else:
        print('Função Remover: Arquivo não existe')

''' # Usar posteriormente 
## - Verificar existência do arquivo - ##
import urllib2

def se_existe(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        return True
    except:
        return False
######### - fim da verificação - #########
'''


baixar_ontem()
baixar()
extrair()
remover()
```